# HTML <form> tag causing Rails form to submit a GET instead of POST request

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, get, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a form that works fine until I add the   tags for styling (I am using twitter bootstrap). The app is Rails 3.1 and I am on a mac. Here is a form that works fine with no issues:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert-message error">
    <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<%end %>
```

Then, when I add the  tag to the same exact form like this:

```
<form class="form-stacked">
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert-message error">
    <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<%end %>
</form>
```

This form appears to issue a GET request instead of a POST request. Instead of redirecting me upon save like it does without the  tag, I see this in the URL:
http://localhost:3000/signup?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=Pt1vOp7lykCPFdj5BJeZ6xwJM2vy0JomMGSKoB%2FyYpU%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=test%40get.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=kevin&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=kevin&commit=Create+User

I have tried specifying post in both the rails and HTML. Specifying it in rails using :method => post yields the same results (the GET request and URL info above). Using  in the HTML looks like a POST request but the User object isn't saving (I belive this is the case because I am not getting redirected to the root_url, which is set in the controller and works fine when not using  tag). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. `form_for` produces the `<form>` HTML, right? Why do we need extra tags around it?

Comment: I was adding the tag to specify a class needed by twitter bootstrap for styling (I'm new to Ruby and Rails). I guess if the form tag is being generate anyways, I could just add something like :class => "form-stacked" ? Where would I be able to specify that?

Comment: I found the answer thanks to Matchu pointing me in the right direction. In order to add the class to the <form> html generated by Rails, I had to do this:

    <%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "form-stacked"} )  do     |f| %>

This worked fine. I'm still not sure why having 2 <form> tags would generate a GET request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want this:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :class => "form-stacked", :id => "something" } do |f| %>
  stuff goes in here as before
<% end %>
```

Comment: leave out the id if you only need to add a class, it's just for show

Comment: ha! Just added that to the comments. you beat me to it. Thank you. Any ideas why a GET request would be submitted? Just curious

Comment: ah, that's a good question, I can't figure it out either but I do know that a form inside a form is invalid html, so perhaps the browser is trying to best-guess here. You may find the functionality differs from one browser to another.

Comment: Interesting... I may try to figure it out at some point! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kcurtin: HTML `<form>`s don't nest so the browser only saw `<form class="form-stacked"> form controls </form>` (i.e. the outer form), the default `method` attribute is GET and the default `action` is the current URL.