# HAML rails form_for not calling POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, form-for

I have a form name ( feedback ) and i'm trying to submit it.

However, it keeps calling the GET HTTP method. I've tried adding the :method => :post for the form_for parameters but it still doesn't work. Can I know why it's not calling the POST method ?

> rake routes:

```
      Prefix Verb URI Pattern             Controller#Action
   feedbacks POST /feedback(.:format)     feedbacks#create
new_feedback GET  /feedback/new(.:format) feedbacks#new
        root GET  /                       welcome#index
```

> FeedbacksController

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
    @feedback.save
  end

  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  private
    def feedback_params
      # params.require(:feedback).permit(:  )
    end

end
```

> feedback/new.html.haml

```
.container.col-xs-12.col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.col-lg-8.col-lg-offset-2
  .WhiteSpace

  =fa_icon "coffee 2x"
  =fa_icon "coffee 2x"
  =fa_icon "coffee 2x"
  %h4 Help us serve you better by telling us what you think !

  .WhiteSpace


  %form.form-horizontal
    =form_for(@feedback, :method => :post) do |feedback|
      .form-group
        %feedback.label_field.col-sm-2.control-label <b>Name</b>
        .col-sm-6
          =feedback.text_field(:name, :class =>"form-control" ,:placeholder => "Name")

      .form-group
        %feedback.label_field.col-sm-2.control-label <b>Email (optional)</b>
        .col-sm-6
          =feedback.text_field(:email, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Email")

      .form-group
        %feedback.label_field.col-sm-2.control-label <b>Tel No. (optional)</b>
        .col-sm-6
          =feedback.text_field(:telephone_no, :class => "form-control", :placeholder =>"Telephone No.")

      -#TODO: Use Ratyrate
      .form-group
        %h3.col-sm-2.control-label!="<u>Services</u>"

      .form-group
        %feedback.label_field.col-sm-2.control-label <b>Delivery</b> :
        .col-sm-6
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
      .form-group
        %feedback.label_field.col-sm-2.control-label <b>Friendliness</b> :
        .col-sm-6
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
      .form-group
        %feedback.label_field.col-sm-2.control-label <b>Price </b>:
        .col-sm-6
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
          =fa_icon "star-o 2x"
      .form-group
        %feedback.label_field.col-sm-2.control-label <b>Message:</b>
        .col-sm-6
          =feedback.text_area(:comment, :class => "form-control", :placeholder=> "Comment",:rows =>"10")

      .form-group
      =feedback.submit("Submit", :class =>"btn-primary btn-lg btn-block")
```

My output after clicking Submit looks like this.
[image]

Comment: instead of `:method => :post`, try with `url: { action: "create" }`

Answer (score 3):

Don't nest forms

```
%form.form-horizontal
  =form_for(@feedback, :method => :post) do |feedback|
```

should be

```
=form_for @feedback, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |feedback|
```

By default, a form will submit the form with the GET method.  But the rails `form_for` method uses POST by default.  You don't need to explicitly set the method to POST or the set the action to `create`.

Often, the form partial is rendered in `new` and `edit` and will submit to either the create and update actions, depending on the state of the object (@feedback in this case). In the update action, the form_for method will set the method of the submit to PUT (or PATCH).  Explicitly setting this to POST would conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys after trying out different solutions that i can find through stack, this works for me.

[HTML <form> tag causing Rails form to submit a GET instead of POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161995/html-form-tag-causing-rails-form-to-submit-a-get-instead-of-post-request)

In the comments, one of them explained the reason:

> @kcurtin: HTML s don't nest so the browser only saw  form controls  (i.e. the outer form), the
>   default method attribute is GET and the default action is the current
>   URL.